# How to duplicate a fields value to a new field in solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I currently have documents in Solr with the following tag

FirstName:Some name
LastName:Some name

I would like to add to all the documents another tag Full Name that will concat FirstName + " " + Last Name

Is there some way to do this (I do not want to use a copy field since in the future I will insert values into Full name directly

Thanks,

Shimon

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you don't want to use copyfield as this is what exactly it's for.  You could do via your schema.xml file as follows:

```
<field name="FullName" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="FirstName" dest="FullName"/>
<copyField source="LastName" dest="FullName"/>
```

Then simply remove the copyfield from the schema when no longer needed and re-index your collection.

Another alternative if you are using DIH would be to join the first and last name together into a string seperated with teh space and then insert that into your FullName field:

Schema.xml:

```
<field name="FullName" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

db-data-config.xml

```
select table.FirstName + " " + table.LastName as 'dbFullName'
...

<field column="dbFullName" name="FullName" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried the first solution, but this seems to work only for new documents I insert and not for existing documents. Do I need to re-index my data (What is the fastest way to perform this)? As for the DIH I read about this but I could not understand exactly what I need to write in my db-data-config.xml file can you sahre an example?

Comment: Hi Shimon, Yes copyfield will only add data into the FullName field at the stream index time.  As with any changes such as this in the Schema file you are always best to re-index.  For DIH best starting point is here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Comment: thank you. What would the best way to re-index be (assuming I can't keep a local copy of the data)

Comment: Is the data coming from a DB or are incrementally adding data as you go?  how are you currently adding data?

Comment: loading data from external API using java (incremental)

Comment: Not sure how you go about re-indexing then Shimon.  Not sure if you can refresh the data in anyway from your API.